# Use of the Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I am making use of Google Map in my website, and I want to have the Google Map with user interface i.e when the user selects the location and after pressing submit button the map should display the location. For this I have written a code. But it is not working properly. Can anybody help me writing this code properly to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?
sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
        var myOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
            });
  }

function selectedLocation() {
 var selected = document.getElementById("location").value;
  if (selected == "Location 1") {
        var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.017, 37.914);
        map.setCenter(location1);
        map.setZoom(12);
}
 else if (selected == "Location 2") {
        var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.269, 28.665);
        map.setCenter(location2);
        map.setZoom(12);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

  <p>
        <form action="#" >
    <select  id="location">
        <option value="None">-</option>
        <option value="Location 1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="Location 2">Location 2</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" onclick="selectedLocation()">submit</button>
</form>
  </p>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "is not working properly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

**ERROR #1**
You seem to have a copy/paste error, whereby you have a fragment of options (see below between asterisks):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        **position: latlng,
        map: map,
            });**
```

**ERROR #2**
You have an issue with scope associated with your `map` variable.  It should be global, so you should declare it outside of your initialize function.

---

Working code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?
sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
        function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
        var myOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }

function selectedLocation() {
 var selected = document.getElementById("location").value;
  if (selected == "Location 1") {
        var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.017, 37.914);
        map.setCenter(location1);
        map.setZoom(12);
}
 else if (selected == "Location 2") {
        var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.269, 28.665);
        map.setCenter(location2);
        map.setZoom(12);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

  <p>
        <form action="#" >
    <select  id="location">
        <option value="None">-</option>
        <option value="Location 1">Location 1</option>
        <option value="Location 2">Location 2</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" onclick="selectedLocation()">submit</button>
</form>
  </p>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```